Running docker run commands from a shell script without sudo or docker group
I have a containerised command I'd like to run: docker run my_docker_image. Rather than install the command's dependencies into the main computer, I'm packaging them all into an image, that then users can run via a shell script.
My question is: can my users run this without the following?

giving users sudo access
giving users access to the docker group

I'm keen to not give sudo access unless I have no other choice. Ideally they'd just run a shell script that performs the docker run, and they would have no permissions access, to simplify ongoing permission management of the users.
Even more true for the docker group. This is far too powerful a group to add all my users to.
Is it possible to make the shell script itself able to perform a docker run, without making the user able to as well?

Is rootless docker an alternative?

@vidarlo I am having a look at that, but more fundamentally, I don't want my users to have access to docker at all if I can avoid it. If for no other reason that I don't have to dive into the permissions world of docker, and what can/can't be allowed.

If you don't want your users to have access to it you can't let your users access it. That's really the only answer.

What's wrong with sudo? give them access to the single command to start the container and nothing else.

@GeraldSchneider that would be fine, but I don't understand how the command would have permission to start the container.

I was thinking something like "write a script that's owned by the docker group and use setguid", but I am a relative shell beginner and I don't know if that's a terrible idea!
